# How to convince "The Management" to use all aspects of Visual Studio Team System?

Tags: tfs, process, project-management, software-quality

Currently we have several defect and bug tracking systems, which include Quality Centre and bespoke support systems (both team and company wide).  Also we use Microsoft Project  - although I haven't seen a task list in months...

But what I find difficult to understand is why our company purchases VSTS and only utilises part of it - we currently use source control, automated overnight builds and team testing functions.

How can our team convince "The Management" to use project task items, defect tracking, reports and process guidance parts of the system?  Surely this would save time and money once implemented correctly  ?

Comment: Nice question, totally off-topic. Would have a better place either on [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) or [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you already have the VSTS licenses then why does your team management need to sign off on anything? Start the features amongst your team for small areas and gradually ramp it up. Would you ask management to sign off on which text editor you use?

Management have a basic fear of anything that in any way may disrupt productivity, and rabid adoration for anything that increases productivity at no risk to themselves. Start small and let the results sell themselves.

This is how I've introduced both Unit Testing and Wikis at previous companies. When the results begin to show people quickly want to get involved.

Comment: Good answer, but what about if you are in a company where you do need to get management approval for every piece of software used (text editor included)?  In addition you may not have the permissions to use VSTS fully and need to get signoff on access rights.

Comment: As somebody once said, "it's easier to beg forgiveness later than it is to ask permission now" :)

Answer (score 0):

Tell them if they not decide to, then in one hour you start to kill hostages every five minutes 10 at the time...

But more serious do the meeting with management or write some kind of request and show what time consumption it takes to use disintegrated system, and how powerfull and underused newly bought system is, but before do soem analyses if system does really fit all current ne4eds. But be carefull with your words and names,. If it really comes out that company got underused equipmentsoftware which got negative impact on productivity and information flow in company, and it means less of valuable work even heads can fall for this. It all depend how serious is your company in that cases.

Be aware that it would be not quire fluent process to switch frome one soft yo another, people got own habbits and things that they are used to so you will have to do this in some steps which include graduall introducing people to new system